# Batch script - dir /b is including directory names and empty lines in output file

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, command

I run this script to list backup files older than 8 days and delete them in a server, and it behaving weird recently. Please see below

```
::Find backup files older than 8 days
::/p Specifies the path from which to start the search.
::/s Instructs the forfiles command to search into subdirectories recursively.
::/d Selects files with a last modified date within the specified time frame.
::/c Carries out the command specified by String and then stops.
::/b Displays a bare list of directories and files, with no additional information.

PUSHD \\SERVER_NAME\M$\MSSQL
FORFILES /P Backup /s /d -8 /C "cmd /c dir /B @file">K:\ScriptLogs\OutPut
POPD
```

This was working fine recently until I created more folders inside \SERVER_NAME\M$\MSSQL\Backup like FULL, DIFF, LOG as

```
\\SERVER_NAME\M$\MSSQL\Backup\FULL
\\SERVER_NAME\M$\MSSQL\Backup\DIFF
\\SERVER_NAME\M$\MSSQL\Backup\LOG
```

And the K:\ScriptLogs\OutPut file is now including the folder name FULL as below

```
FULL
SERVER_NAME_DB_DIFF_2021_06_10_040135.diff
SERVER_NAME_DB_DIFF_2021_06_11_040124.diff
SERVER_NAME_DB_DIFF_2021_06_12_040213_1.diff
```

I'm not able to understand why it is including FULL in the output list (if my cmd is wrong it should include DIFF and LOG too).

And when i modified the code as below

```
PUSHD \\SERVER_NAME\M$\MSSQL
FORFILES /P Backup /s /d -8 /C "cmd /c dir /A-D /B @file">K:\ScriptLogs\OutPut
POPD
```

It gives error as below, and output file is not including FULL now (as /A-D excluded Dir's)

```
K:\DBScripts>PUSHD \\SERVER_NAME\M$\MSSQL

W:\MSSQL>FORFILES /P Backup /s /d -8 /C "cmd /c dir /A-D /B @file" 1>K:\ScriptLogs\OutPut
File Not Found
File Not Found

W:\MSSQL>POPD
```

My concern here is why it is including FULL directory name in the older code version and the code run gives error with new version. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why you're using `Dir` at all? What is wrong with `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "Backup" /S /D -8 1>"K:\ScriptLogs\OutPut"`? Also what you need to understand is that forfiles, despite its name, does not only output files, it also works with directories. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `forfiles /?`, and press the [`ENTER]` key, you should clearly see that you can omit those directories using `@IsDir==FALSE`. For example: `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "Backup" /S /D -8 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"If @IsDir==FALSE Echo @File\"" 1>"K:\ScriptLogs\OutPut"`.

Comment: Does seem quite odd that you are running the DIR command when FORFILES is already iterating the files. That is a lot of overhead.

Comment: Thanks @Compo for your inputs, however it add double quotes to the file names. And i use this output to compare with another list 'FINDSTR /p /g:K:\ScriptLogs\OutPut K:\ScriptLogs\OutPut\ON_TAPE_LIST>K:\ScriptLogs\OutPut\delete3'  and it gives me nothing as the source filenames has quotes.. I'm new to batch scripting. Thanks

Comment: So your response to us is that you were using `dir /A-D /B @file`, to remove the enclosing doublequotes. So for that you should use `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "Backup" /S /D -8 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"If @IsDir==FALSE Dir @File /B /A:-D\"" 1>"K:\ScriptLogs\Output"`. Although I'd prefer, `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "Backup" /S /D -8 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /Q /D /C \"If @IsDir==FALSE For %%G In (@File) Do Echo %%~G\"" 1>"K:\ScriptLogs\Output"`. In either case, as you can clearly see, the fix to your issue was still, the use of `@IsDir==FALSE`.

Comment: What about `forfiles /S /P "Backup" /M "*" /D -8 /C "cmd /Q /C if @isdir==FALSE for %%I in (@file) do echo(%%~I"`?

Comment: Thanks @Compo ... your script helped me a lot. Thanks again. Got some pointers for batch script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @compo ....

```
PUSHD \\SERVER_NAME\M$\MSSQL
FORFILES /P Backup /S /D -%NUMBER_OF_DAYS% /C "cmd /Q /D /C \"If @IsDir==FALSE For %%G In (@File) Do Echo %%~G\"" 1>K:\ScriptLogs\OutPut-%dtStamp%
POPD
```

This fixed the issue.